# Derived attribute with AsTajson call in the custom service

Tags: mdriven

I use  .net5 and .netStandard from nuget. The structure of the solution is simple - class library with ecomodel and webapi project.
I've registers custom service in the EcoSpace1.cs as it was advised by eco gurus long, long time ago.

```
public interface IMyService
{
    int Class1Count();
}

public class MyServiceClass : IMyService
{
    private IEcoServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public MyServiceClass(IEcoServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public int Class1Count()
    {
        var v = ServiceProvider.GetEcoService<IOclService>().Evaluate("Class1.allInstances->size");
        return (int)v.AsObject;
    }
}
```

The rule for a webapi project's controller- inherit from the Controller class - due to the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (swagger) usage. Swagger shows errors if I inherit a controller from the ModelDrivenControllerBase

But the code above is OK, the GET works perfect:

```
public class MySecondEcoServiceController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public int Get()
    {

        using (EcoSpace1 es=new EcoSpace1())
        {
            es.Active = true;
            int r = es.MyService.Class1Count();
            return r;
        }
    }
```

}

It works till I tried to add another method into the IMyService and to get json. I tried AsTajson by adding derived attribute to the Class1 with DerivationOcl.

```
Class1.allInstances->first.AsTaJson( 'SampleViewModel',  false )
```

or

```
self.AsTaJson( 'SampleViewModel',  false )
```

In the MyServiceClass the implementation of the Get is:

```
Class1 v = (Class1)ServiceProvider.GetEcoService<IOclService>().Evaluate("Class1.allInstances->first").AsObject;
json = v.Attribute2;
```

If I tried GET this value - exception:

```
Eco.FrameworkImpl.Ocl.EBoldOCLError: 'bughuntinfo internaleval:84  es seems fine.Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

What is the proper way (or EcoService?) to get values returned by TaJson?

Comment: OK: var v = ServiceProvider.GetEcoService<IOclService>().Evaluate("Class1.allInstances->first");  but this KO: ServiceProvider.GetEcoService<IOclService>().Evaluate("Class1.allInstances->first.AsTaJson( 'SampleViewModel',  false )");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but please check that you have initiated use of ViewModels once for your EcoSpace type:

```
ViewModelDefinitionsInApplication.Init(_es);
```

Comment: done, and it works! Thanks a lot!